# How to create multiple graphs with TitanDB (+Cassandra) in the same machine?

Tags: cassandra, graph

I'm experimenting with TitanDB (with Cassandra as storage) + Rexter.

I've been reading the documentation during hours and trying to create multiple graph DBs on the same machine, but I didn't find the way to do it.

I find two main problems:

- In the TitanDB docs, the Cassandra section tells how to create a graph on Cassandra, but the only parameters they comment are the host and the port, there isn't any reference to the graph name :s).
- In the Rexter section we have essentially the same problem. We can define a list of named graphs, but every graph only can be mapped to a 3-tuple (backend type, host, and port).

The only way I can imagine is to instantiate more than one Cassandra server, and make that each Cassandra server listens to a different port. Then, configure Rexter to map every graph to a different cassandra instance.

There is a way to create more than one graph using the same Cassandra instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and, based on smurty's answer, I managed to do it by adding a new property 'storage.cassandra.keyspace' for each declared graph in rexster-cassandra-es.xml configuration file.

Since I'm using version 0.5.4 with default Cassandra+ElasticSearch configuration, [this is the documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/titan-config-ref.html#_storage_cassandra) that helped me.

Now I have one graph using the keyspace 'titan' (default value), and another one with the exact same configuration except for that property, which has value 'global'. In folder '$TITAN_HOME/db/cassandra/data' there are two folders, 'titan' and 'global', one for each graph's data.

Comment: After creating graph like mentioned above, how can we access the other graph with gremlin rest client?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra
scroll down to "Cassandra Specific Configuration", and
use property "storage.keyspace=" to use multiple keyspaces in cassandra.
Each keyspace will hold a graph. (default keyspace is 'titan'.

So, if you want 3 graphs, create 3 config files, with diff "storage.keyspace" property.

When you open a graph from your client using TitanFactory.open(config), use the appropriate config file.

Answer (score -1):

> *There is a way to create more than one graph using the same Cassandra instance?*

[This useful tutorial](https://medium.com/@jbmusso/serving-multiple-titan-graphs-over-gremlin-server-tinkerpop-3-d3c971d07964#.hlb0ke263) is about precisely that:

> 1. Define each Titan graph storage and indexing backends
> 2. Configure Gremlin Server to initialize the graphs at launch
> 3. Reference each graph Traversal object in the Gremlin Server .groovy bootstrap script